# How do I fix very quiet audio input on a MBP 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

I am using headphones at work that I also use at home. The difference is that my computer at home is an MBP **2015**. The headphones work fine there. They are basic 4 pin phone earbuds, with volume and play/pause.

But even at max input volume the audio is barely audible unless the output volume is at max. I tapped a pen against the mic pickup and it's only audible at >50% volume (which is actually loud for listening to music or video, I usually keep my volume at 20%).

Work computer is a 2016 MBP, the one with the touchbar. Home computer is 2015 MBP, no touchbar.

These headphones pick up audio fine when plugged into a 2015 MBP and an Android phone. It's safe to say the headphones are not the issue.

What is the difference here and how do I fix it?

[image: audio settings]

Comment: You're using an external microphone - are you certain it's functioning properly?    Can you try another?

Comment: I’m unclear about a few points. Please clearly identify the model of computer you use at work and which you use at home. You have MBP 2017 in the title, yet you bold face **2015** in the body of your question. Please indicate what works on the 2017 and how it differs from the 2015.

Comment: @IconDaemon it seems pretty clear. Please re-read the first two sentences. Work model is a 2016 15 inch MBP. Edited title, since 2017 was a guess.

Comment: @Allan just did a voice recording with those headphones on my Android phone and they are working fine

Comment: If you are convinced that your headphones are fine (see this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271) then it's possibly your input jack.  In that case, you need a better interface.  See this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259681/119271

Comment: Why would they work fine on a 2015 MBP and stop working fine on a 2016 MBP? Was there some change to the chipset or something?

Comment: Apple used an entirely different TRRS config - they swapped Mic and Gnd pins - for their products (like Apple has *never* done things differently than everyone else).  It's not out of the realm of possibility they changed the pin outs of their socket to conform to the rest of the industry.  I don't have access to schematics to verify, but it's not hard to test with a different mic.

Comment: Just noticed...the first link I gave you was incorrect.  This is the correct one:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239472/control-macs-volume-with-headphones/239564#239564

Comment: I have a feeling this may be due to some damage near that area. The machine apparently got wanged on that corner, the display has lines because of it. Waiting on a replacement. I doubt it's a TRRS connector issue -- these headphones actually record audio, it's just very quiet. If Mic was going to Gnd I'd think there would be no audio at all.

Comment: Given that you said the Mac got damaged near that area, it's quite possible there's a bad connection.  The link I gave with the USB interface will be your best fix.

Comment: Try using a different microphone on both computers. If the problem persists, then something is up with your home mac.