# Controlling a microphone connected via combo jack

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, garageband

**Short verstion (TL;DR)**

I have a microphone connected to my new MacBook via a splitter adapter (see the picture below), in which you can use the multifunction jack separating the input and output channel, in order to be able to use it not only for headsets, but also to connect audio input sources.

The system says there is an "external Microphone / iPhone headset" device, and I can hear the mic if I test it when I connect it using the splitter, so I guess it detects it.

But it is not listed among the audio input devices, so there is no way to control it, that is using it as input in applications (Skype, Garageband) or changing its volume.

Do you know a way to make this work?

**Long version (all details)**

**Background**

Based on the accepted answer to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/macbook-pro-mid-2012-microphone-input) question I have connected my microphone to my new MacBook via its multifunction combo audio jack, using a 3.5mm 4 Position to 2x 3 Position 3.5mm Headset Splitter Adapter - M/F (see the picture below). The purpose of this adapter is to split the audio channels connected usually to a headset, separating the input and the output, in order to be able to connect a microphone or an audio source just to the input channel.

[image]

**What works**

It works and the systems seems to detect it. In particular, I can hear the microphone on the speakers/headphones. Plus, if I click on "About this Mac" and afterwards on the "Overview" tab I click on "System report", I see a window where if I click on Audio I can also see an item called "External Microphone / iPhone headset", which is the mic channel of the headset, which is what is detected when I connect the Mic like this.

A screenshot of this is below (see the red arrow).

[image]

**What does not work**

But when it is detected like this, the systems seems to not consider it as a proper microphone or audio input, and because of this you cannot control it, that is selecting it as source in applications like GarageBand/Skype or controlling its volume.

In fact, when you want to select the audio source for an application like GarageBand or Skype, it just doesn't appear, and I only see "built-in microphone" in the menu, while I would expect to also see the "External Microphone / iPhone headset) which appears if I click on "System report" as explained in the "what works" section.

Plus, perhaps because of this problem, I cannot even **control its volume**, which is quite low.

**Possible explanation**

The system seems to just recognize that it is connected as part of a *headset* (because I connected it using the splitter above, again see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/macbook-pro-mid-2012-microphone-input) question for details), but nothing more.

**Question(s)**

Do you know any advanced setting (or terminal tool) for MacOS or any external application capable of controlling an audio input device (mic or musical instrument) connected like this, in particular setting it as the primary audio input or controlling its volume?

Alternatively, do you know any software capable of making the OS see this audio input device as a normal device instead of seeing it just as part of a headset?

Comment: This question is worth answering (if there is an answer), but as a workaround, search your online electronics store of choice for "usb audio interface" and you'll find options for getting sound-in through usb.

Comment: Thanks @dwightk for the comment, it will be useful for other people seeing this. I am just trying to understand if there is a solution for the problem above, if there isn't I had already planned to buy an usb audio adapter.

Comment: I would have to disagree that "it works"  If the "system detects" it as you say, you should see a wired microphone, not the built-in microphone as your input device.  That said, I am unclear of what you mean by "controlling".  What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: Hi @Allan , when I say that it works I mean that if I click on "About this Mac" and afterwards on the "Overview" tab I click on "System report", I see a window where if I click on Audio I can also see an item called "External Microphone / iPhone headset", which is the mic channel of the headset, which is what is detected when I connect the Mic like this. But when it is detected like this, the systems seems to not consider it as a proper microphone or audio input, and because of this you cannot control it, that is selecting it as source in applications like GarageBand or controlling its volume.

Comment: I will add this clarification on the question

Comment: Can you post a photo of that screen?

Comment: Audio Hijack *might* help out and show the input source. They have a free trial, you can record anything up to 10 minutes and after that they start overlaying noise on the track. It might be worth a try since it is free. https://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/ (although I guess that doesn't pass the audio onto another app, just lets you record the audio.)

Comment: Thanks for the pic...it helps.  After thinking about it, what *may* be happening is that it's "detecting" the headset because it sees the impedance of the speaker, but it's not on the correct pin.  I would make sure it works with a ["proper" TRRS Apple headset](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239472/control-macs-volume-with-headphones/239564#239564). If it does, the issue is the adapter.

Comment: Thanks @dwightk I will try your solution soon and keep you updated.

Comment: Oh thanks @Allan looking at your answer to that question might be really useful! So, based on that answer, you are suggesting the problem is that my jack may not be compliant with the standards used by iPhone headsets? So, I might need a splitter compatible with this standard, or a converter from the standard I am using to this standard? Based on what you say, it seems my current adapter might be CTIA (or OMTP), since in the past I used it successfully to connect an mp3 player to my _smartphone_ using the mic channel, so it must have the format used for smartphones at this point.

Comment: That about sums it up.  Personally, I would use a [USB interface](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295595/how-to-connect-a-3-5mm-microphone-not-amplified-to-an-imac-for-recording/295628#295628) rather than the "all-in-one" jack.  It actually reduces complexity and gives you a better interface with more control.

Comment: I agree about the USB interface (although the price difference is relevant, the USB interface seems to be at least 10 times more expensive in the best case), but I am still tempted to try the extremely cheap jack solution just because I would like to understand better how my own built-in jack port works... Considering that the price is so low, perhaps I will try soon and make sure about the cause of this... and even if I solve this with the jack, I may still want to buy the USB interface anyway because of what you've just said :-)

Comment: @dwightk the hijack tool does not detect the mic as well unfortunately.

Comment: I can't speak for the quality of the interface, but amazon has usb interfaces in the sub-$10 range that I'd guess were at least useable.