# Headset microphone is not being recognized as input source

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone

I have a Razer kraken essential headset (p2) , but my mac (2017 13-inch, running mojave 10.14.6) won't recognize my headset's microphone.

The output source is doing fine (shows "Headphones on Headphone port"), but when it comes to input source my mac only shows the "internal Microphone" option.

But what is weird, because my razer headset's microphone works on both linux and windows machines, and i have tested another headset (a hyperX one, p2 aswell) and the microphone works just fine on my mac.

I am kinda lost here on where to search for solutions to this problem. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: this may be Apple and Razer wiring their headphone jacks differently, it may be that different rings on the jack itself only match up with the L/R speakers and not the mic.

Comment: both LR speakers works just fine, this does not exclude the possibility of rings not matching ?

Comment: This answer might shed some light on the issue:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239564/119271

Comment: Thanks for linking this question, but i don't see how this explains the fact that another headset (hyperX) works on windows/linux/mac and my Razer just works on linux/windows. If the plug is inverted, the hyperX headset should not work on my mac aswell. You see my point ? it is kinda weird, it doesn't seem like a hardware limitation (on my non-expert perspective).