# Why my voice recording has a buzz sound if I use an external 3.5 cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a Macbook Air. When I use my Apple headphones with a 3.5 extension cable to record or speak in a video call (Zoom or Google Meets), there's always a buzzing sound. The other person can hear that sound. If I record my voice using Voice Memos, I can hear it too. I made sure the extension cable jack has 4 conductors when I purchased it. It should be good to use.

If I use my Airpods to record my voice or join a video call, there's no problem.

Comment: Did you get the right 4-conductor adapter?  There’s a [TRRS for Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239564/119271) and another for everything else.

Comment: I knew Apple reversed the conductors but didn't take into account when buying this one. Thanks. I'll take a look.